# how to call multiple URLs within array at same time using node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, api, axios

**When I have different types of URLs in a single array of strings, in my JSON file, Now I use the map function to post data via apiurl**

*an array of URLs:*

```
 "ResponseServer": [
        "https://ResponseServer1/home/",
        "https://ResponseServer2/home/",
        "https://ResponseServer3/home/"
    ],
```

*Map function*

```
     Responseserver.map((Resposnserver) => {
            axios.post(Resposnserver, data)
}}
```

every time the function reads each array of URLs, but I wish to call all APIs at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const responses = await Promise.all(Responseserver.map((url) => {
  return axios.post(url, data)
})
```

Promise all will throw an error if at least one API call fails, you can use [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) if you need to fulfill all the API calls despite any rejections.